# Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage - Rhino error in unit testing C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, rhino-mocks-3.5

Having gone through the net forums, still unable to rectify this error in my unit testing for the below line.

```
SetupResult.For
    (strategyFactory.RuleByMailRoomProcess(null, out isMailRoomRequired, out currentAndMailRoom))
        .IgnoreArguments()
        .Return(currentAndMailRoom, isMailRoomRequired, currentAndMailRoom);
```

Initially, it worked fine, but the line was  like below:

```
SetupResult.For(strategyFactory.RuleByMailRoomProcess(null))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Return(currentAndMailRoom, isMailRoomRequired, currentAndMailRoom);
```

I had to add two out parameters and I did. But it throws the error as below:

> Error 166 The type arguments for method
>   'Rhino.Mocks.SetupResult.For(T)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
>   Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   C:\Me\ControllerBaseTests.cs    473 13  UnitTests

Could someone help me please, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make it compile, simply add the type explicitly:

```
SetupResult.For<ResultType>(strategyFactory.RuleByMailRoomProcess(null, out isMailRoomRequired, out currentAndMailRoom))
    .IgnoreArguments()
    .Return(currentAndMailRoom, isMailRoomRequired, currentAndMailRoom);
```

If you want it to be inferred successfully, you have to investigate why the inference fails. Most likely RuleByMailRoomProcess is overloaded and can return multiple types.

Comment: Sorry, your code is not compiling, but throws error saying"Void cannot be converted to "ResultType"

Comment: Well "ResultType" is just illustrative, obviously you should put the correct type in there, which in this case is "Void"...

Comment: Even then it didn't build/worked. The solution that fixed was, to remove test case which is wrongly written as above. It will not take more than one parameter. Can you observe that?